# Is it possible to leave tooltip on screen until the mouse moves away from the icon on ie 8?

Tags: javascript, yui, tooltip

The mouse-over text in the Web UI displays for about 6 seconds. Is it possible to leave it on screen until the mouse moves away from the icon? Some of the help text is longer than can be read in 6 seconds.

I am using YUI for tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have documentation of this tooltip

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/tooltip/#config

Check this setting: `autodismissdelay`

Comment: I don't want to set tooltip for specific time. Is it possible to leave it on screen until the mouse moves away from the icon?

Comment: I don't see other way in the documentation. Try to set autodismissdelay to for ex. 5 minutes and test it. When you move out your mouse it shoould dissapear right away.